# Converting a number to an UnsignedByte in PHP

Tags: php, json, types, unsigned

I wish to pass jSON data as POST to a RESTful web service using PHP.

The json data to be passed one field is said to be an **UnsignedByte**

`{"merchantNumber": "214", "meterNumber": "371315479968"}`

the value **meterNumber** is the one that has to be *UnsignedByte*

I need help in coverting the value to UnsignedByte like so

```
    function convertToUnsignedByte( $string ){     
         $result = '';// DO SOMETHING WITH $string;
         return $result;
        }

        $string  = "14656575668";

        $data = json_encode(array(
                              "merchantNumber": $merchantNumber, 
                              "meterNumber": convertToUnsignedByte($string)
                               )
                           );
```

Comment: What do you mean `UnsignedByte`? What value do you expect to have with `371315479968`? (or another example)

Comment: `371315479968` is too large for an unsigned byte; range of an unsigned byte is 0-255

Comment: Here's a description of json-data types: http://ubjson.org/type-reference/value-types/#numeric

Comment: Thank you everyone, the problem was with the RESTful API Documentation which had errors, it is the one that requires fields to have UnsignedBytes, lol